# What exactly does LocalClusteringCoefficient compute for directed graphs?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

For undirected graphs, the [`LocalClusteringCoefficient`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LocalClusteringCoefficient.html) of vertex `v` is

```
GraphDensity[Subgraph[g, AdjacencyList[g, v]]]
```

What precisely does Mathematica compute for *directed graphs*?  The documentation states that this function supports directed graphs.

To take an example, can someone explain the result `1/2` for vertex `1` here?

```
g = Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1, 1 -> 4}, 
  VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
LocalClusteringCoefficient[g]
(* {1/2, 1, 1, 0} *)
```

What about `1/3` here?

```
g = Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1, 1 -> 4, 4 -> 1}, 
  VertexLabels -> "Name"]

LocalClusteringCoefficient[g]
(* {1/3, 1, 1, 0} *)
```

---

[Also asked on Wolfram Community.](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/753542?p_p_auth=xxf3XfvE)

Comment: I'm really not sure what it calculates, I just want to add that `GraphDensity[Subgraph[g, AdjacencyList[g, v]]]` works for directed graphs as well as mentioned in the reference for [`GraphDensity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphDensity.html?q=GraphDensity) and seems to give the correct results for both cases.

Comment: @Graumagier Well, "correct" depends on how we define the local clustering coefficient :)  `GraphDensity[Subgraph[g, AdjacencyList[g, v]]]` "works" (as in it returns some well defined result) for directed graphs, but it's good to remember that `AdjacencyList` ignores edge directions while `GraphDensity` doesn't.  This is reasonable, but another potential definition would be to only consider neighbouring vertices along out-edges (not in-edges), or something similar. Thanks for looking at the question!

Comment: My best guess is that it's computing the cyclic clustering coefficient $C_i^{cyc}$, see p.13 of this [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0612169.pdf).

Comment: @ilian Yes, you are correct!  How did you find that?  Did I miss something in the documentation?

Comment: @Szabolcs Done. Unfortunately, the documentation remains silent on this. My guess was based on a peek at some bug reports, looking up some common conventions and experimenting with a couple of graphs.

Comment: @ilian Is there any way you could get this fixed (i.e. explained) in the documentation?

Comment: @Szabolcs: After so many years passed, I wonder whether you solved the above problem with `LocalClusteringCoefficient` for directed graphs. Can we use MMA's code for LCC computation?

Comment: @TugrulTemel Ilian explains what this function computes in his answer. There is no standard definition of a directed clustering coefficient. As the paper he links shows, there are multiple possible generalizations to directed graphs. Mathematica happens to choose one of them. Which one(s) are useful would depend on the application.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Thank you very much for your quick answer. It means MMA applies `cyclic clustering coefficient` using a simple graph structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Transitioning my comment into an answer per [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs)

> My best guess is that it's computing the cyclic clustering coefficient $C_i^{cyc}$, see page 13 and earlier of [Fagiolo, G., 2007. Clustering in complex directed networks. Physical Review E, 76(2), p.026107](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevE.76.026107) ([arXiv link](http://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0612169.pdf)) for the definition.

Comment: As your paper,I think cannot explain the vertex 3th's cyclic clustering coefficient [in this case](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9lwMh.png)

Comment: @yode I think this function converts multigraphs to simple graphs internally.

Comment: Why are you so smart?:)

Comment: Do you think you could get this into the documentation?  I got burnt again because I forgot that it handled directed graphs specially and I assumed it ignores edge directions ... If you think that writing to support about this would help, let me know.

Comment: @Szabolcs Don't want to sound pessimistic, but I had personally reported it to the appropriate people and nothing happened, so I'm not holding my breath.