# Computing the local clustering coefficient for a directed graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am trying to replicate Mathematica's `LocalClusteringCoefficient` function (as well as compute $C_i^{out}$) for a directed graph. Which was presumed that Mathematica calculates as the cyclic clustering coefficient, $C_i^{cyc}$ in this post: [What exactly does LocalClusteringCoefficient compute for directed graphs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101399/what-exactly-does-localclusteringcoefficient-compute-for-directed-graphs/101820#101820)
The equation comes from page 13 of this paper, also linked in Szabolcs's [post](https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0612169.pdf):

$$C_i^{cyl}=$$ $$(A)_{ii}^3\over d_i^{in}d_i^{out}-d_i^{\leftarrow\rightarrow}$$
    Where:
    $$d_i^{in} = (A^T)_i  1$$
    $$d_i^{out} = (A)_i  1$$ 
    $$d_i^{\leftarrow\rightarrow}=(A)_{ii}^2$$

A = Adjacency Matrix, $(A)_i$ = $i$-th row of A, 1 = N-dimensional column vector $(1,1,....1,)^T$

For a graph `g`:

```
g = Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1, 1 -> 4}, VertexLabels ->"Name"]
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
s = Range[VertexCount[g]];
one = Table[1, Max[VertexCount[g]]];

din = Transpose[AdjacencyMatrix[g]][[#]] & /@ s;
dout = AdjacencyMatrix[g][[#]] & /@ s;
dlink = b2.b2.b2

numer = dout.dout.dout
denom = (din.one).(dout.one) - dlink;
numer/denom
%.one
```

With these results:

```
(* {1/3, 2/3, 1/3, 0} *)
```

However, `LocalClusteringCoefficient[g]` yields:

```
(*{1/2, 1, 1, 0}*)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is incorrect.  Here is a direct implementation:

This is the adjacency matrix:

```
am = AdjacencyMatrix[g];
```

$(A^3)_{ii}$ in the formula refers to the $i$th element of the diagonal of its cube:

```
numerator = Normal@Diagonal@MatrixPower[am, 3]
```

You can get the in- and out-degrees of the vertices using [`VertexInDegree`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexInDegree.html) and [`VertexOutDegree`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexOutDegree.html).

We also need the degrees of reciprocal connections. A simple way to get these is to first construct an adjacency matrix of reciprocal connections, then sum up its rows:

```
Total[am Transpose[am]]
```

Then we are ready to compute the denominator of the formula:

```
denominator = VertexOutDegree[g] VertexInDegree[g] - Total[am Transpose[am]]
```

Finally just take the ratio:

```
numerator/denominator
(* {1/2, 1, 1, Indeterminate} *)
```

The indeterminate comes from `0/0`. One way to avoid it is to use

```
div[0,0] = 0;
div[x_,y_] := Divide[x,y]

MapThread[div, {numerator, denominator}]
```

You can do it in many other ways of course.

---

**Your code:**

It would help if next time you commented the code, and indicated what each line is meant to do, like I did above with my code.

```
s = Range[VertexCount[g]];

one = Table[1, Max[VertexCount[g]]];
```

I do not understand `Max[VertexCount[g]]`.  `VertexCount[g]` is a number. What is the point of `Max`?

```
din = Transpose[AdjacencyMatrix[g]][[#]] & /@ s
```

Why are you defining a function and mapping it?  The result is simply `Transpose@Adja

```
dout = AdjacencyMatrix[g][[#]] & /@ s;
```

Same comment as above.  Also, it is confusing to me to see the adjacency matrix and its transpose be called `dout` and `din`. These names suggest degree vectors.

```
dlink = b2.b2.b2
```

`b2` is not defined, so I can't comment on this.

```
numer = dout.dout.dout
```

The result is a matrix. The formula asks for its diagonal. You are not taking the diagonal.

```
denom = (din.one).(dout.one) - dlink;
```

`din.one` is a weird way to obtain in-degrees.  If you need to do summation, use `Total` on the adjacency matrix.

`(din.one).(dout.one)` is the *dot product* of the degree vectors, and the result is a number.  The formula has an element-wise product and the result should be a vector, not a number.

(In case this is what confused you: there is no indication of Einstein summation convention being used in this paper.)

Comment: Thanks. I was working on calculating the in & out clustering coefficients and bumped into a complex infinity from "1/0", I can define `div[1,0]=0`; but it seems that I should define it as `div[any numerical value, 0]=0;` Thoughts?